# The US visa tracker says that the application is in "Administrative Processing", but the consulate said it was approved?

Tags: usa, application-status

After applying for a US visa and being told that the visa was approved, the status on the [Department of State website](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx) still says that it's in "Administrative Processing". What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Administrative Processing" is the default state for all applications and is not a reason for concern. As soon as the visa is physically stamped in the passport (which can take from 1 to 5 days, depending on the current workload), the status on the website will change to "Issued".