# The visa officer at US embassy said my visa is approved but when I check the status, it is saying refused

Tags: usa, visa

I have applied for an F1 visa. After being interviewed by the visa officer, they said my visa is approved and gave me a blue leaflet. They didn't say anything about administrative processing.

Here is a point to be noted. At the time of the interview I had failed to provide a recent photograph; the photograph I provided is more than 6 months old. There was a person who initially checked every document and mentioned that the photo was not recent. I said I didn't have enough time, hence I couldn't manage my recent photograph. The person said not to worry, that I could submit one later.

When I arrived home, I received a mail requesting me to "please be advised to submit new photographs (2 copies) taken within the last six months, along with a copy of this email, at your pre-selected document collection center." On the next working day, I submitted a recent photograph, as requested.

Now when I am [checking my status](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx), it states "REFUSED".

Should I be worried?

[image: Redacted image of document stating Refused]

Comment: Your application is probably on hold until the requested photographs have been incorporated into the application.

Comment: It says on the refusal "you will be contacted if further information is needed" - you were, and here is the confirmation. It appears to be refused for administrative reasons, will continue to be processed, and you will receive another adjudication when complete.

Comment: The big-print wording seems unnecessarily aggressive compared to the small print.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what did u mean ?

Comment: @mSapps "Refused" sounds (to my ears) like a final decision, not an intermediate state of the application. The text makes it clear that it may be either one, as the other comments (actually they are more like answers) explain.

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17284/the-us-visa-tracker-says-that-the-application-is-in-administrative-processing

Comment: It says "You will receive another adjudication once such processing is complete" -- in other words, once the picture is processed, then the status can change once again.